# Jackson Map Null Json to List

Tags: json, groovy, jackson

I've searched and found [Jackson ObjectMapper throwing NullPointerException even with NON_NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754835/jackson-objectmapper-throwing-nullpointerexception-even-with-non-null), but I don't have control of the class to change my setter.

I have am being given

```
{... "fieldNames": null,...}
```

and am supposed to deserialize it to

```
Collection<String> fieldNames
```

I don't have control of the class or the json I'm getting.

Is there some setting I can use to handle for this? I've looked at [DeserializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html), but could not find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mix-ins when you don't control the class you are deserializing. You don't mention the name of the class containing `Collection<String> fieldNames` so lets assume it's called `Fields`. Then create a new class:

```
class FieldsMixin {
    @JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)
    Collection<String> fieldNames;
}
```

and add the mixin class to your `ObjectMapper` associating it with the original unmodified class:

```
mapper.addMixIn(Fields.class, FieldsMixin.class);
```

This is a new feature in Jackson 2.9 and as you guess it will skip calling a setter method or otherwise set a field if the value in JSON is null. [Documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html)